# How to integrate canvas-gauges.js into fabric.js as a fabric.js Object?

Tags: html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am working in a project which has Drag and droppable elements,
Here I am using two plugins
first one is fabric.js and another one is canvas-gauges

I need to generate gauges by using canvas-gauges plugin, and add it as an object of fabric.js

**My current result**
[current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8ZVN.png)

**My expected result**
[expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b637B.png)

I have tried fabric.js custom objects but it was not working properly for me.
anyone can please help me to fix this problem ?

I'm attaching my codesandbox link - [codesandbox.io/s/goofy-curran-c9chd1?file=/src/App.js](https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-curran-c9chd1?file=/src/App.js)